# catkin_create_pkg

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-kinetic, catkin-create-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I installed ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 into Docker container. I created catkin workspace according to beginners tutorial. But when I try to create package, I get following exception:

```
$ catkin_create_pkg ahoj
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/catkin_create_pkg", line 68, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/catkin_create_pkg", line 61, in main
    newfiles={})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package_templates.py", line 209, in create_package_files
    _safe_write_files(newfiles, target_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package_templates.py", line 185, in _safe_write_files
    fhand.write(content)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Did you meed this situation somebody? It seems like function `_safe_write_files`
`fhand.write` expects different data type than what it gets, but I don't understand why.

Thanks in advance for any idea,
Radim

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249398/catkin_create_pkg/) by [raada](https://answers.ros.org/users/28717/raada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your stacktrace shows that you have installed `catkin_pkg` for Python 3.5. The Debian package provided in the Xenial repository from ROS is using Python 2. So it looks like you have diverged from how you setup ROS on your machine.

You should uninstall `catkin_pkg` from `/usr/local` and follow the installation instructions: http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raada](https://answers.ros.org/users/28717/raada/) on 2016-12-05**:
Thank you - this was the reason!

I installed MORSE simulator from source code that requires python3 and I built catkin_create_pkg using python3 as its dependency. So the problem was between chair and keyboard;-)